# Choose view select statement dynamically by session variable in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with session variables and I would want to create a view which does the following:

```
if (myVar=1)
  select * from my_table where X
else
  select * from my_table where Y
```

Where X and Y are different clauses.

Is it possible?

Can this be implemented with a regular select statement (or I need stored procedures)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 'A'
FROM tableA
WHERE current_setting(setting_name) = 'setting A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B'
FROM tableB
WHERE current_setting(setting_name) = 'setting B'
```

Details on postgresql session variables [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html).

UPD It will give the results of one of the `SELECT`. If `current_setting(setting_name)` equals to `'setting A'` the first query will return the results, but the second wont.

For your example the query will look like:

```
SELECT 'A'
FROM tableA
WHERE myVar = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B'
FROM tableB
WHERE myVar != 1
```

UPD Checked: postgres executes only one of the queries. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` shows that the second query was planned but marked as `(never executes)`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a union of the select, but one of the two depending on the variable value.

Comment: @AvnerLevy look at the `WHERE` clause. It will give you only one of the queries.

Comment: Thanks, I've missed that. I wonder if Postgres is smart enough to avoid performing the non relevant query.

Comment: @AvnerLevy My guess - it is. To be sure - `EXPLAIN` this query with different `myVar`. The plan will show what postgres will do.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use stored procedures or UDF (if your RDBMS supports them). As you cannot pass parameters to a view, a view is not suitable. However, you can achive something like that by creating a view like this

```
create view MyView as
select 1 as MyVar, * from A
union
select 2 as MyVar, * from B
```

and filter the column MyVar in your application

```
select * from MyView where MyVar = :MyVar
```

However, this usually involves a table scan of the whole view. Again, depending on the RDBMS you may be able to put an index on the column 'MyVar' and speed up this approach.

I recommend using a stored procedure, it makes your attempt more clear.

Comment: I haven't tried this *specific* case, but PostgreSQL is usually smart enough to push conditions down into a view. Try it with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and see how the query is being executed; you might find that Pg is applying the filter to both branches of the union rather than producing all the results and then scanning them.

Comment: Since each of the queries has a large performance impact it isn't practical for me to do it this way. I'm looking for a way that Postgres will choose upfront from the two.